# Using PHPOffice/PHPSpreadsheet in Joomla

Tags: joomla, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

Any experience in getting Joomla to load the PHPOffice classes?
Using Sourcerer in articles to write PHP code and would like to integrate to PHPOffice

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to include any (large) amounts of PHP inside of articles, it is generally slow and difficult to maintain. Your best option would be to develop a component to use the PHPOffice class and then include the result on your desired pages, using one of the following options:

- Ditch articles altogether and use the component to display your pages
- Make a module to extend the component and display this on an article page
- Load the component into the article using the Components Anywhere extension

The Joomla website has lots of information on developing components and the GitHub page for the PHPOffice repos also has lots of examples.